# Why is my retrofit model returns null? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

So I'm trying to use themoviedb for extracting search results for movies. The url is as follows:

[https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key={apikey}&language=en-US&query={query}](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=%7Bapikey%7D&language=en-US&query=%7Bquery%7D)

Where in the query I insert the keyword that I want to search. I'm using retrofit library to do this.

This is my code for my ApiService:

```
interface ApiService {
    @GET("3/search/movie?api_key=${BuildConfig.MOVIE_TOKEN}&language=en-US&")
    fun getMovies(
        @Query("query") query: String
    ): Call<SearchMovieResponse>
}
```

This is my code for the ApiConfig object:

```
class ApiConfig {
companion object {
    fun getApiService(): ApiService{
        val loggingInterceptor =
            HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.themoviedb.org/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
        return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

}

I also have a `RemoteDataSouce` class which uses that config to get the movies. I have also generated the data class to using POJO. This is the method in the `RemoteDataSource` class that uses that the API config.

```
fun getMovies():List<MoviesItem>?{
    val client = ApiConfig.getApiService().getMovies("john")
    var listMovies: ArrayList<MoviesItem> = ArrayList<MoviesItem>()
    client.enqueue(object: Callback<SearchMovieResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<SearchMovieResponse>, response: Response<SearchMovieResponse>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                val rawList = response.body()?.results!!
                for (item in rawList){
                    listMovies.add(item)
                }
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<SearchMovieResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            return
        }

    })
    return listMovies
}
```

The json response of the API is this:
[image: JSON]

The data model that I use for `SearchMovieResponse` is this:

```
data class SearchShowResponse(

@field:SerializedName("page")
val page: Int? = null,

@field:SerializedName("total_pages")
val totalPages: Int? = null,

@field:SerializedName("results")
val results: List<ShowsItem?>? = null,

@field:SerializedName("total_results")
val totalResults: Int? = null
)

data class ShowsItem(

@field:SerializedName("first_air_date")
val firstAirDate: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("overview")
val overview: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("original_language")
val originalLanguage: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("genre_ids")
val genreIds: List<Int?>? = null,

@field:SerializedName("poster_path")
val posterPath: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("origin_country")
val originCountry: List<String?>? = null,

@field:SerializedName("backdrop_path")
val backdropPath: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("original_name")
val originalName: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("popularity")
val popularity: Double? = null,

@field:SerializedName("vote_average")
val voteAverage: Double? = null,

@field:SerializedName("name")
val name: String? = null,

@field:SerializedName("id")
val id: Int? = null,

@field:SerializedName("vote_count")
val voteCount: Int? = null
)
```

However, the listMovies is returning null. I'm not sure what I did wrong here. Can anyone explain? Thanks

Comment: Show json and SearchMovieResponse

Answer (score 3):

Your method `getMovies()` is returning the list before the Retrofit call is done, you are using `enqueue()` method that run it asynchronous so your method finish before the `onResponse()` method is called.

Solution, rewrite your code thinking about this information or use `execute()`method instead `enqueue()`, this will execute the call in the main thread so you will have to call it in a new thread or a coroutine.

Comment: Is there any way where I can just return it inside the enqueue method?

Comment: @BrianMohammedCatraguna the most easy thing would be to update the adapter of your data in the onResponse() method, start the recyclerview with an empty array then when the onResponse method completes, update the adapter with the real data.

Answer (score 1):

As, you are using **enqueue()** that run  *asynchronous* so your function finish before the **onResponse()** method is called. So you have to return the list after on the complete of the process.

```
 fun getMovies():List<MoviesItem>?{
        val client = ApiConfig.getApiService().getMovies("john")
        var listMovies: ArrayList<MoviesItem> = ArrayList<MoviesItem>()
        client.enqueue(object: Callback<SearchMovieResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<SearchMovieResponse>, response: Response<SearchMovieResponse>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    val rawList = response.body()?.results!!
                    for (item in rawList){
                        listMovies.add(item)
                    }
                  return listMovies
    
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<SearchMovieResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                return
            }
    
        })
    }
```

Comment: When I put the return inside the if block I get an error saying that it requires Unit instead of
kotlin.collections.ArrayList<MoviesItem>

Comment: Yeah, function need some return. Remove return from the function and add your list where I have place the return.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get what you mean by removing the return from the function. So do I revert back to my code before? And adding the list do you mean the adding to listMovies?

Comment: First tell me, After you get the list where you are setting it. Are you setting to recyclerview?

Comment: Yeah, I'm planning to. Right now I'm just trying to try whether the connection works and I'm just getting one item from the list and one property of the item to set on a textview.

Comment: just set that in onresponse after the loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231696/discussion-between-brian-mohammed-catraguna-and-ahmad-bajwa).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use callback to return your list:

```
fun getMovies(callback: (List<MoviesItem>) -> Unit) {
    val client = ApiConfig.getApiService().getMovies("john")
    client.enqueue(object : Callback<SearchMovieResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<SearchMovieResponse>,
            response: Response<SearchMovieResponse>
        ) {
            var listMovies: ArrayList<MoviesItem> = ArrayList<MoviesItem>()
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val rawList = response.body()?.results!!
                for (item in rawList) {
                    listMovies.add(item)
                }
            }
            callback(listMovies)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<SearchMovieResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            callback(emptyList()) // or throw error or use Result structure
        }

    })
}
```